# «Такую..., как»

Tags: синтаксис

Можно ли писать в отрыве «такую..., как»:
«В качестве примера можно привести такую организацию, стоящую на позиции охраны прав граждан, как адвокатура».

Answer (score 3):

Можно. "Такую..., как" - это двойной (парный) союз, каких достаточно много в русском языке.  
Возможно, вас вводит в заблуждение обособленное определение. Конечно, если между "такую" и "как" будет много информации, то читатель может забыть про первую часть союза и значение "как" ему будет уже непонятно, но в вашем примере всё нормально.

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае запятая перед "как" -  по случаю границы обособленного определения.Она имеет право на существование.

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Но лучше: "В качестве примера организации, стоящей на позиции охраны прав граждан, можно привести адвокатуру". Хотя, честно говоря, адвокатура в качестве примера все равно не смотрится. Этот институт - единственный в своем роде. Да и "организацией" назвать её довольно сложно. Впрояем, все зависит об "большого" контекста, т.е. от общей направленности текста.

Answer (score 0):

Такого правила, которое возбраняло бы разрывать парные союзы, а в данном случае "Такую..., как", нет.

Comment: А чем их, извините, разрывают?

Comment: Разорвать - это не только "вскрыть пакет", "разорвать пальто","разорвать договор" и т. д., но и разъединить что-то соединенное, разделить на части. Конечно, слово " разрывать" можно заменить на "разделить". Главное, чтобы человеку, нуждающемуся в нашей подсказке, было понятно, можно так написать, сказать или нет. Когда вы читаете комментарий, вы же смысл слов с опечатками понимаете и для вас, наверное, главное суть ответа?!

Comment: ТАКОЙ далёкий от истины ответ, Соан, КАК ваш, сбивает с толку ТОГО человека, отчаянно желающего узнать правду, КОТОРЫЙ задал этот вопрос.     
Этот мой комментарий полон ошибок из-за того, что я разорвал парные союзы членами предложения, да?

Comment: Я практик, а не теоретик, и мой ответ НЕ МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ ДАЛЕК ОТ ИСТИНЫ, потому что я в своей работе руководствуюсь правилами рус. яз. Надо объяснять так, чтобы было понятно. Если человек в чем-то сомневается, то он нуждается не в высокопарном ответе, а в доступном.  Я не думаю, что автору вопроса не понятен мой ответ. Кстати, не зарабатывайте баллы, пытаясь над кем-то возвыситься. Задающий вопрос сам решит, какой вопрос верный, потому что на этом сайте нет дилетантов. Между прочим, я воспринимаю ответ целиком, а не копаюсь в ошибках. И всегда благодарю того, кто помог мне разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

В чем, собственно, заблуждение? Разумеется, такая конструкция имеет место быть.

«В качестве примера можно привести такую организацию, стоящую на позиции охраны прав граждан, как адвокатура».

Рассмотрим предложение. В данном случае мы видим причастный оборот. Главном слово - организацию (в начальном форме: организация). Организацию, (что делающую?).

Answer (score -2):

Здесь ставится запятая для выделения "стоящую на позиции охраны граждан". Запятая относится именно сюда. Если бы этой "вставки" не было, тогда запятая не ставилась бы.

Comment: Ирина, а при чем здесь "вставка"? Двойные союзы пишутся с запятой перед второй частью: не только..., но и; не столько..., сколько; такой..., как.

Comment: Тогда бы оно звучало так: В качестве примера модно привести такую организацию как адвокатура. Тут запятая не ставится.

Comment: Ирина, приведенные Вами примеры относятся к совершенно разным типам предложений.
"Я как учитель..."- это предложение с приложением. Запятая не ставится, если  "как" в значении "в качестве" или характеризует предмет с одной из сторон.
В предложении "В качестве примера можно привести такую организацию, как адвокатура" совсем другая конструкция, а именно с двойным союзом "такую...,как". Здесь обязательно ставится запятая.

Comment: Ирина, вы попросту не различаете парные союзы и конструкции с "как".    
 Если есть слово "такой" и ему подобные, которые по логике указывают, что вскоре встретится слово "как", то это уже в любом случае парный союз.